# How do I execute command for each stdin line?

Tags: bash

I've got the following command:

```
$ cmd-a | while read -r line; do echo "${line}"; cmd-b; done
```

This works well, and will for all intents and purposes look like `cmd-a` is just printing its stdout as normal, but for each line we execute `cmd-b` as well.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

`cmd-a | xargs -n1 cmd-b` would be nice, but it splits on all whitespace (I know GNU xargs has the `-d` option, but it's unfortunately not available to me,) and would suppress the output of `cmd-a`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman good point, thanks! You're right, I *do* want the output of `cmd-a` to be written to stdout as well as the output of `cmd-b`. I'll update the question to be clearer.

Comment: @anubhava not sure what you mean. I know what process substitution is, but how would you apply it in this case?

Comment: `while IFS= read -r line; do echo "${line}"; cmd-b; done < <(cmd-a)`

Comment: This is perfectly clean, idiomatic code, [in line with best practices](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). Why do you want something different?

Comment: Right @anubhava I see what you mean now, but that doesn't execute `cmd-b` (I'm guessing this is just an oversight) and isn't really easier to read *or* write. (Perhaps I should update the question to say "Is there a way to do this, which is less cumbersome to read and write?" rather than the "cleaner" comment?)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy right, "clean" isn't perhaps the right term to use. Really what I'm looking for is something more terse but without losing the readability of it, if that makes more sense?

Comment: Ahh. Terseness is the enemy of correctness in bash -- I strongly advise against making it a priority.

Comment: BTW, anubhava's suggestion means that changes to shell state (variables, ets) made in your loop are visible to the outer shell, so it *is* worth considering. See also [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I don't necessarily disagree, but this is turning out to be a very common pattern for us and I guess before I write a utility for it I figured I'd check with the hive mind if there's a "better" way. Much obliged for you commentary and the BashFAQ link – hadn't seen it before!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The existing proposal is entirely idiomatic and clean; [BashFAQ #001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) advises precisely the same mechanism to iterate over input line-by-line. There's no reason to replace it, but if you're using it frequently, it may make sense to encapsulate it.

Consider the following function:

```
for_each_line() {
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
    line=$line "$@"
  done
}
```

...thereafter run as:

```
cmd-a | for_each_line cmd-b
```

...or, if your `cmd-b` is a function and you want it to be able to modify shell state, the above can be invoked as follows (per [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)):

```
for_each_line cmd-b < <(cmd-a)
```

...which will make the preceding line available to `cmd-b` in the environment, should it have any reason to modify its behavior based on the value of same.

Comment: Solid answer – much obliged!

Comment: One bug -- my original code was using `echo` rather than `printf`. That means that with bash running stock options, a line containing only `-n` would disappear; that a bash with the `xpg_echo` option enabled could behave differently; and that on other POSIX-y shells, [behavior was extremely poorly-defined](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html) -- see in particular the APPLICATION USAGE section of the linked standards document. Amended appropriately.