# inotifywait -m | echo "found an event" doesn't stay open despite monitor switch

Tags: bash, inotifywait

For whatever reason this command is quitting out after creating a single file in the folder. Not sure why when it is in monitor mode

```
$ inotifywait -m  /TDPROXY/NET_DISCONNECT/INCOMING/ -e create  | echo "new file"
```

Thanks

Comment: `echo` doesn't read from standard input. When `echo` completes, it closes its end of the pipe, and `inotifywait` receives a SIGPIPE signal the next time it tries to write.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this problem and figured it out using [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46818496/inotifywait-not-staying-open-with-m-monitor-switch#comment80584791_46818496).  If you just run

```
$ inotifywait -m /TDPROXY/NET_DISCONNECT/INCOMING/ -e create
```

You'll see a stdout line printed everytime the event fires.  So you just need a way to run `echo` whenever that happens.

I found a way from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40613445/3006854).

```
$ inotifywait -m /TDPROXY/NET_DISCONNECT/INCOMING/ -e create |
while read -r line; do echo "new file: ${line}"; done
```